# Android Error or Bug Idk?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, system

ok so here's the problem in eclipse I am making a metric to standard and back calculator but I keep getting errors and I had to delete one of my layouts and remake it but now when I remake it it brings up the old layout and I am so confused and now when I try to edit it and save it I get this as a popup message:

title:Update Conflict

message:The file '/TemperatureConverter/res/layout/measurement.xml' has been changed on the filesystem. Do you want to override changes made on the file system?

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Eclipse may bug out from time to time. Have you tried restarting it?

Comment: yea I did and it wont work...

Comment: and I don't want to exit again because my edit wont be saved and if I do try to save it i'll get that same popup.

Comment: Copy your changes into a text file incase you lose them and override the file in your file system.

Comment: @zgc7009 already done that

Comment: It just doesn't work all I get is this error after I do it "document structures must start and end within the same entity."

Comment: Have you tried closing eclipse, manually deleting the file from your file system again, starting eclipse and seeing what happens? It may have bugged out on the first deletion attempt. Definitely sounds like a weird bug though.

Comment: Um idk wtf it's doing now but I shutdown eclipse, deleted the file, and made a new one then cleaned it and now my measurement.java file is recognizing it again but it thinks that there's a EditText and a Spinner still what the hell is it doing?

Comment: there isnt anything in the new layout why is it recognizing it still?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it I just had to do allot of deleting and cleaning...  sorry for wasting your time guys